# Accesing individual values in PropertyGroup via .prop in the menu

Tags: interface, properties

I need some help with properties. I have a property class, pretty straight forward stuff

```
class My_Settings(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    prop_1: bpy.props.IntProperty(name="Some prop", default=0)
    prop_2: bpy.props.IntProperty(name="Another prop", default=0)
```

I register the class and assign it to scene as

```
bpy.types.Scene.my_props = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=My_Settings)
```

I use another class to add instances of those properties:

```
class My_add_property(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "add_fields"
    bl_label = "Add input fields"

    def execute(self, context):
        inst_prop = bpy.context.scene.my_props.add()
        inst_prop.prop_1 = 0
        inst_prop.prop_2 = 1
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

I draw a menu, use My_add_prop as a button to add instances

```
class My_menu(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "my_menu"
    bl_label = "Menu"

    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout = lay
        lay.operator('add_fields', text="Add prop")

        '''But I have no idea how to access individual properties do draw them into menu.
         I assume it's going to be something like that, but how can I actually get to
         individual values?'''

        for i in bpy.context.scene.my_props:
            lay.prop(context.scene, "my_props")
            lay.prop(context.scene, "my_props")
```

Also, ts there a method to remove last property set? I'd like to make class/button that removes the last set.
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally figured it out. the last block in the menu should look like that

```
 for i in bpy.context.scene.my_props:
        lay.prop(i, "prop_1")
        lay.prop(i, "prop_2")
```

Now i feel kind of stupid...
Also if you want to go on removing last set of properties, you can go with

```
bpy.context.scene.inset_props.remove(1)
```

This appears to be removing sets of properties one by one until it hits the (1) one.

Hope it helps someone in the future!